# Not able to call callback function properly, while creating a thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

```
void foo(ActionQueue* actions) {actions->pop();}
std::thread ActionQueue::run_all_in_thread()
{
    std::thread t(foo, this);
    return t;
}
```

Error:-

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccPzKuQx.o: in function `std::thread::thread<void (&)(ActionQueue*), 
ActionQueue*, void>(void (&)(ActionQueue*), ActionQueue*&&)':
exercise.cpp:(.text._ZNSt6threadC2IRFvP11ActionQueueEJS2_EvEEOT_DpOT0_[_ZNSt6threadC5IRFvP11ActionQueueEJS2_E vEEOT_DpOT0_]+0x37): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Basically, I want to create a function that returns a thread and while creating a thread in that function I am getting the above error.ActionQueue class;-

```
class ActionQueue {
    std::queue<std::unique_ptr<Action>> actions;
    std::mutex mutex;
public:
void push(Action *action) {
    actions.push(std::unique_ptr<Action>(action));
}
std::unique_ptr<Action> pop() {
    std::unique_ptr<Action> action(std::move(actions.front()));
    actions.pop();
    return action;
}
bool empty() {
    return actions.empty();
}
void run_all();
std::thread run_all_in_thread();
};
```

And here I am using it.

```
std::thread t1(std::move(actions1.run_all_in_thread()));
```

Comment: `undefined reference to \`pthread_create'`: You have `-pthread` in the command line of your compiler? (It seems like not.)

Comment: I have included the <thread> library.

Comment: There is a difference between `#include`s (effect the compiler) and libraries (effect the linker). The `-pthread` option might do even more than adding the necessary libraries. (It might influence the generated code in the compiler as well.)

Comment: @rahulyadav: error is not in your code, but in the build chain configuration.

Comment: See first comment, is what you should do. "You have -pthread in the command line" seems pretty explicit.

Comment: Yeah, as @Scheff mentioned, you need to have -pthread in your build command to add support for threading (see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-pthread ).  How are you building this? Are you in an IDE, are you using a Makefile, calling g++ on the command line?

Comment: I am using Makefile and calling using g++ in ubuntu. Yes, I am getting the point mentioned by @Scheff. I added lib in Makefile but result is same.

Comment: No it's not a lib you need to add. Forget libs. You need `-pthread` as part of your build command in order to build threaded code. `g++ -pthread main.cpp`

Comment: Thanks got it. Working perfectly.